# How to use UNIX find to find (file1 OR file2)?

Tags: regex, unix, find

In the `bash` command line, I want to find all files that are named `foo` or `bar`. I tried this:

```
find . -name "foo\|bar"
```

but that doesn't work. What's the right syntax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want:

```
find . \( -name "foo" -o -name "bar" \)
```

See the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find) page (of all places)

Answer (score -1):

I am cheap with find, I would use this:

```
find ./ | grep -E 'foo|bar'
```

Thats just my personal pref, I like grep more than find because the syntax is easier to 'get' and once you master it there are more uses than just walking file tree.

Comment: I like the syntax. Why was he voted down? Is it inefficient? What does dot slash do?

Comment: It would also find all files in directories which contain foo or bar as a substring.

Comment: find dot should be sufficient. If you are using GNU find, then even the dot can be omitted.

Comment: It would, but that is pretty easy to deal with by using the handy regex expressions...